# Web Api 2.2 - OData is expanding data without $expand parameter

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, odata

According to the documentation, OData is supposed to just return the entity directly queried, unless $expand is passed to fetch related entities. But that isn't how it's behaving for me. I have an endpoint to fetch a Child entity, but even if $expand is not passed, it still returns the Parent data as well.

How do I stop this from happening? I want the documented behaviour:

`/api/Child?$top=10` to return top 10 Child entities

`/api/Child?$top=10&$expand=Parent` to return top 10 Child entities and include the Parent data.

I'm using Web Api 2.2 and EntityFramework 6.1.3 on .NET 4.6.1, Visual Studio 2015.

Controller:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<Child>))]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Child> Get()
{
    return _repo.GetChildren();
}
```

DataLayer:

```
public IQueryable<Child> GetChildren()
{
    return Context.Childs;
}
```

Model:

```
public partial class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Hitting endpoint /api/Child?$top=1 returns:

```
"value": [
    {
      "ChildId": 1,
      "Name": "(child name)",
      "ParentId": 3387,
      "Parent": {
         "ParentId": 3387,
         "ParentName": "(parent name)",
         "DateUpdated": "2017-06-23T11:42:06.013+01:00"
      }
    }
]
```

How do I stop it returning the Parent data unless I ask for it?

Comment: I think I've worked out the pattern of behaviour here, but no wiser how to stop it doing it.

There was no endpoint for the Parent class. It seems that OData will expand all related entities if there is no endpoint defined. If I add a ParentsController and add builder.EntitySet<Parent> to WebApiConfig, Child no longer returns the Parent data without being asked to. If I remove the builder.EntitySet<Parent> from WebApiConfig, Child returns the Parent data again. So I can reproduce the issue, but I haven't managed to stop it.

Comment: I tried using .HasOptional(c => c.Parent), which does remove the Parent data, but then if I try to fetch the Parent data via /Child(1)/Parent, I get a 406 error. I can see the code hit a breakpoint in ChildController.GetParentFromChild(), which is the naming convention for a navigation property, but after returning IQuerable<Parent> the response gets turned into 406 Not Acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

First let's look at the SQL that is being generated by the DbContext.

To do that simply add the following line in your "Context" constructor:

```
this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

If your SQL contains a "JOIN" to your "Parent" table, then your entities are being eagerly loaded... I would check in your data layer or your context to see if you may be including the Parent entity..

```
... Context.Child.Include(s => s.Parent)
```

I recreated your scenario and yes, it should be working as you're expecting it to.

Comment: I logged the SQL, and it's actually lazy loading each Parent entity one by one.

Comment: Weird thing is, I tried adding .Include() to another entity - and for that one OData is NOT returning the included entity. It seems to be doing the exact opposite of whatever I think it should be doing. I've also had weird problems with EntityFramework this morning, where I've added an association between 2 not-nullable columns (both in the database and in EF they are not null) and EF has failed to compile because it says there are nullable dependencies. I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: By stepping into the repository code, it looks like it might be OData that is the problem, because at the point where the query object is created, it has the correct join (or no join), but when the SQL actually runs, it's changed to the incorrect query.